# JPA can't find existing column in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm using simple spring CRUD app with JPA (Spring Boot).

I have model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    //code

    @Column(name = "birthDay")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String birthDay;

    //code
}
```

My postgreSQL:

```
create table Person(
   id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   country varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   birthDay varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   age int check ( age >= 0 ) NOT NULL,
   email varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   phone varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

My repository:

```
public interface PeopleRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PeopleService {

    private final PeopleRepository peopleRepository;
    @Autowired
    public PeopleService(PeopleRepository peopleRepository) {
        this.peopleRepository = peopleRepository;
    }

    public List<Person> findAll(){
        return peopleRepository.findAll();
    }

   //code with another methods
}
```

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/tables")
    public String tablesPage(Model model){
        List<Person> people = peopleService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("people", people);
        return "tables.html";
    }
```

My 'tables.html'

```
This is part of my table (not all html-code):

<tr th:each="person : ${people}">
   <td th:text="${person.getName()}"></td>
   <td th:text="${person.getCountry()}"></td>
   <td th:text="${person.getBirthDay()}"></td>
   <td th:text="${person.getAge()}"></td>
   <td th:text="${person.getEmail()}"></td>
   <td th:text="${person.getPhone()}"></td>
</tr>
```

So I have an error:

```
Error: column p1_0.birth_day doesn't exist
```

and

```
JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.id,p1_0.age,p1_0.birth_day,p1_0.country,p1_0.email,p1_0.name,p1_0.phone from person p1_0] [Error: column p1_0.birth_day doesn't exist Position: 25] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
```

But I don't have 'birth_day' column!

In Person-class it calls 'birthDay' and in postgre database it also calls 'birthDay'.

Why JPA search for 'birth_day' column?

And how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: bahman karami
What should I do and how?

Comment: bahman karami
But I've already had that annotation.
See my code above.

Comment: bahman karami
Nope, you had to use double quotes because in other case you'll get an error. It says that single quotes only for chars.

Comment: Try this :@Column(name = "'birthDay'") Or "\'birthDay\'";

Comment: Are you using spring boot

Comment: Doesn't work. I think the problem isn't in quotes because it work with "name", "age", "email" but doesn't with "birthday". And I don't know why.

PS I even drop my table and create "birthday" with low case and change it in model too but now it says the same: `column p1_0.birthday doesn't exist`.

Comment: Anish B
Yes. Spring boot.

Comment: @AlexJP Did you try adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` in application.properties and see if this works?

Comment: @AlexJP I have added my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't works too.(